# Should i call back if no response after a successful Interview?

Tags: interviewing

I had an interview for Software Engineer. I answered the interview questions well and that person was impressed with the way i have answered. Now almost a week after the interview and i haven't got any call from them. Should i call back and ask whether i got selected or not ? Or wait until they call me ?

Comment: This isn't really an answer but if this is a concern of yours you can always ask during the interview what the next step is and/or when you can expect to hear back from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that there is no universally applicable answer to "how long should I wait to hear from a company after an interview?". I have interviewed with several companies, some of whom are ready with the offer letter right at the end of your interview, and some whom have notoriously long "internal processes" which take several *months* to complete.

I would suggest you get in touch with some other employees of the company to figure out how long it usually takes for them to roll out the offer letter (or invite the candidate for the next round of interview). Glassdoor is often a good place for such investigations, if you do not know anyone in person.

If that doesn't work, I would suggest wait for maybe one more week and contact one of the managers who interviewed you to find out what's going on with your application. Contacting them too early might make you appear desperate, two weeks is usually a reasonable amount of time to wait for (though YMMV, as discussed in the first paragraph).

In the meantime, if you aren't doing this already, I would also recommend you keep looking for other opportunities. You can never be sure that you will get an offer even after an impressive interview, because departments go through "budget freezes", "job role fulfilled internally" and other problems all the time.

Comment: I believe patient is important here as i already have a job.

Comment: Yes, of course, I wrote the answer assuming you already have a job.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things here.  Firstly call them, thank them for the interview, ask if there has been any decision yet, and ask if there is a likely timeline if not.

It can help to vaguely mention other things look like they may be moving, so you're keen to make sure the one's you're interested don't get missed (so you get the message to them you are keen).

After that it's a waiting game, you can touch base again in a week or so to keep showing your interest.

My second point though is to keep looking.  You may have had a great interview, great rapport with the interviewer(s), etc, but the cold hard fact is that a million and one things may have happened:

- An internal candidate may be on a "promise" and you were there to make up numbers,
- The budget could be canned,
- Someone may offer 90% of what you do, but only wants 60% of the money,
- Or worst of all, as well as you did, maybe someone did even better.  It can happen that you do nothing wrong, but you're still second (you may have broken the world record, but here comes Usain Bolt to smash your new record).

A week is a long time to wait with nothing, and yes, from experience I've had decisions that HAVE taken much longer. Usually though, if you are in the frame for the role, there will be some kind of comms to keep YOU interested (even if only to say "we're still discussing it").  If they have delays their end they will be afraid that their favoured candidate will pick up another offer, so they will usually keep in touch, even if they can't say why the delay is happening.

So talk to them, but treat it as a No until you get confirmation otherwise and keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are courteous on how you follow up, there is absolutely no reason why you shouldn't follow up. If you get that how you ask for something is as important as what you ask, there is little to no danger to you that something is going to blow up in your face.

We have had a couple of users on this site who spammed their HR contact at the prospective employer's HR every day within 48 hours of the interview and CALLED them, too. And then asked us what they should do next. Don't do that :)

Comment: you seem to stop mid sentence there.

Comment: @HLGEM Thanks for catching it - at the moment, I can't remember for the life of me what I was thinking at 4 AM, so until I remember, my completion of my midsentence is a patch :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be good to call them to check on progress. That shows that you are interested in the job. People who give advice on such things often say you should call or send an email after an interview saying you are interested, maybe ask a follow-up question.

The trick is WHEN to call. Too soon, and especially if you make multiple calls, and you are just annoying. Too late and they may give the job to someone else. I think 1 to 2 weeks is the generally-recommended time.

If you do call and get a non-committal, "we're still considering all applicants" type of response, especially if they say something to the effect of "we'll call you if ...", I'd work on the assumption that you're not going to get this job. No matter how well you think the interview went, they might have simply been being polite. Or maybe they thought you were an A+ candidate but the next guy they interviewed was an A++ candidate. MAYBE it will still come through, but don't sit by the phone waiting for them to call. Apply other places.